# Conflict on Window.onload JS <-> PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm integrating a preloader on my website responding to window.onload = function();
As long as the preloader is not ready I put a class .none on my main #container. If 
the preloader is ready I remove that class. Problem is that I have to put the .none
class by default in my HTML on my element, so when the user does not want to support 
JavaScript he/she sees nothing. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that users will always have JavaScript enabled by now. The most pessimistic stats put the number of users with JavaScript disabled at 2%. It could be a good idea to ignore this 2% instead of expending all the effort needed to support them, if they're not your target audience.

Comment: @rid you need to take into consideration that most accessibility features (readers for blind people etc) do not support JS as well, so it's not only a browser problem

Comment: @hexblot, indeed, this will not make it easy for screen readers to interpret the HTML, but they don't really have to. If it's a web app for example, that is fully built on JavaScript, they can read the page just as they read any other native app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<noscript>` tag to target JavaScript disabled browsers. Anything that's inside the `<noscript>` tag will only render if JavaScript is not available.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to have a `.nojs` class on the `<body>` element by default. First thing you do with JS ( even before the whole document loads, just add a `<script>` tag under `<body>` and let it run ) is remove that class.

You can then use the CSS selector `.nojs .something` to target things when JS is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a message when user's Javascript is disabled like this:

```
<noscript><h1>Please enable javascript</h1></noscript>
```